# What are the different kinds of personal pronouns in English?

Tags: pronouns

I'm learning pronouns at the moment, and in my book it said that their are different kind of personal pronouns such as reflexive pronoun, subject pronoun, etc. However, there isn't enough data for me to understand. What I want is to know the different kinds of personal pronouns and how to use them.

Comment: How much grammar do you know?  Do you have "pronouns" in your language?  Do you know what a "subject" is?   There could be books written on this subject. Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: What research have you done for this? Just entering "pronoun" into the Wikipedia gives you [**this**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronoun) which looks as if it answers your question.  OK there is quite a bit about linguistics you can skip. If you still have specific problems after reading the article please come back here and update your question.

Comment: Do you mean only personal pronouns such as I, you, he, she, or just every kind of pronouns, like demonstrative pronouns and relative pronouns? Please be more specific

Comment: @Eden0516 just personal pronouns thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned, there are more than one kind of personal pronoun in English. There are total 5 kinds of personal pronouns:

| Subject | Object | Reflexive | Possessive Adjectives | Possessive Pronouns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| I | me | myself | my | mine |
| you | you | yourself/yourselves | your | yours |
| he | him | himself | his | his |
| she | her | herself | her | hers |
| it | it | itself | our | ours |
| we | us | ourselves | our | ours |
| they | them | themselves | their | theirs |

First, let me tell you what are personal pronouns. A **personal pronoun** is a short word we use as a simple substitute for the proper name of a person.

For example:

> John is eating. John loves eating fish. John always eat fish on Thursday.

This sentence is ok, but it is really awkward to keep repeating "John". Hence, we can use personal pronouns (*he* in this example).

> John is eating. He loves eating fish. He always eat fish on Thursday.

Let's have another example:

> Amy and Jay are good friends. Amy and Jay are going to the movies tonight.

Again, it's weird to repeat "Amy and Jay", so we can use *they* instead.

## Subject pronoun

**Subject pronoun** is used as the **subject** of the verb. Let's have a look at the two abovementioned examples.

> John is eating. He loves eating fish. He always eat fish on Thursday.

In this example, **John** functions as a subject, so the pronoun we use for subjects, as its name implies, is called subject pronouns.

## Object pronoun

The subject pronouns is the pronoun for subjects, so what about object pronouns? Yes, it's the pronouns for **objects**. As long as you know what **objects** are, you are able to understand object pronouns.

Example:

> Our teacher is nice. She always give **us** candies.
> Please tell **them** to come in.

## Reflexive pronoun

This is a bit more complicated than the previous ones. Reflexive pronouns are used for the object of a verb when it refers to the same noun as the subject of that verb.

Example:

> Jane shook **herself** awake.

The meaning of the sentence is fairly clear. Jane was drifting to sleep at a time when she shouldn’t be, possibly during class, so she made a sudden movement in order to stay awake. However, if we were to replace the reflexive pronoun with the object pronoun **her**, the meaning changes:

> Jane shook **her** awake.

Most English speakers would read this sentence as meaning Jane was shaking someone else, which suggests a different situation entirely.

Here are some more examples:

> I can do it by **myself**.
> You must finish this test by **yourself**.

## Possessive adjective & Possessive pronoun

Possessive adjectives and possessive pronouns are used to describe that you own or possess something. Possessive adjective and possessive pronouns are nearly the same, with a slight difference:
Possessive adjectives are used to describe a noun, while possessive pronouns are used as a noun.

Example:

> Julia's car is red. **Mine** is blue. ------->Possessive pronoun
> Julia's car is red, but **my** car is blue.-->Possessive adjective

## Attribution

https://www.grammarly.com/blog/personal-pronouns/